# how to use "belongTo" relationship in larvael

Tags: php, laravel-5

i have two models 'users' and 'doctors' i want have used eloquent relatonahiops hasMany and belongaTo to relate them as below

```
This is the model for users
   protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'email',
    'password',
    'role_id',
    'active_user',
];

public function doctor()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Doctor','user_id');
}
```

and the model for doctors is below
     protected $table="doctors";

```
protected $fillable = [
    'role_id',
    'user_id',
    'name',
    'date',
    'gender',
    'specialization',
    'state',
    'country',
    'email',
    'mobile',
    'phone',
    'address',
    'password',
    'pic'

];
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User','user_id');
}
```

now i have a table where i display the doctors using @foreach statement below

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead >
    <tr >
        <th>
            S/N
        </th>
        <th>
            Picture
        </th>

        <th style="text-align: center;">
            Name
        </th>

        <th style="text-align: center;">
            Specialization
        </th>

        <th  style="text-align: center;">
            Phone Number
        </th>

        <th  style="text-align: center;">
            Status
        </th>


        <th style="text-align: center;">
            Book
        </th>
        {{--<th style="text-align: center;">--}}
        {{--Message--}}
        {{--</th>--}}

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php $c=0;?>
    @foreach($doctors as $dr)
        <tr style="padding: 10px; text-align: center;">
            <td>{{++$c}}</td>
            <td>
                <img src='{{url("assets/images/doctors_pic_uploads/".$dr->pic)}}' style="height:40px; width:40px;" class="img-circle">
            </td>
            <td style="padding: 20px;">{{$dr->name}}</td>
            <td style="padding: 20px; ">{{$dr->specialization}}</td>
            <td style="padding: 20px;">{{$dr->phone}}</td>
            <td style="padding: 20px;">

            </td>
            <td style="padding: 20px;">
                <input type="radio" name="book" value="{{$dr->id}}">

            </td>
           This is where i want to show if they are offline or online
        </tr>
    @endforeach


    </tbody>
</table>
```

My Controller is below

```
public function BookDoctors(){
    if(!Auth::check()) {
        return Redirect::to('admin/login');
    }
    $opt=User::findOrFail(Auth::User()->id)->operator->first();
    $doctors = Doctor::all();
    $patients = PatientInfo::all();
    return view('Others.Operator.Appointment.book_doctors')->with(compact('opt','doctors','patients'));

}
```

The Challenge now is that i want to get the "active_user" field from the users migration and include it the form that has a table head of "status" using belongsTo relationship in laravel

Comment: You should be able to access it like this `$doctor->user->active_user`. Have you tried it?

Comment: Tried that it's not working

Comment: Why is it not working? Do you get an error message or something? Any information would be helpful to figure it out.

Comment: yea i get an error message

Comment: Can you edit your question and put it there?

Comment: i finally got it. i used it like this  ` \App\User::find($dr->user_id)->active_user`

Answer (score 1):

[Laravel Documentation One to many Relation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

```
$dr->user->get()->all();
```

Should return all users for that doctor.

Answer (score 0):

Get user details in your query

```
$doctors = Doctor::with('user')->get();
```

In your view file

```
<td>{{$dr->user->active_user}}</td>
```

Comment: it returns an error message "Method with does not exist."

Comment: It should be `Doctor:with('user')->all();`.

Comment: it shows the error now "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::all()
in Builder.php line 2306"

Answer (score 0):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\User;
use App\Doctor;

// ...

public function BookDoctors()
{
    if (!Auth::check()) {
        return Redirect::to('admin/login');
    }

    $opt = User::findOrFail(Auth::user()->id)->operator->first();
    $doctors = Doctor::all();
    $patients = PatientInfo::all();
    $user = Auth::user(); // Retrieve the logged-in user
    $activeUser = $user->active_user; // Get the active_user attribute

    return view('Others.Operator.Appointment.book_doctors')->with(compact('opt', 'doctors', 'patients', 'activeUser'));
}
```